Cannot execute request on any known server - Eureka client can't find the eureka server when containerizing my services inside docker
I got a multi-module system based on spring where each module is a different micro-service. The services use eureka for discovery.
It all works great when I run it on my pc on localhost but now I am trying to run it containerized with docker compose. I've been sitting on this for several days now and I can't find the culprit.
I will preface this by saying that I have a service that runs MongoDB, which my API gateway connects to successfully, so I think the inner network is defined properly.
For simplicity I will reference only the discovery service and my API gateway
This is the docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'
networks:
    ms_network:
        name: ms_network
        driver: bridge
services:
  ms_service_discovery:
    image: ms_service_discovery
    build:
      context: ms_service_discovery
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: ms_service_discovery
    ports:
      - "8761:8761"
    networks:
      - ms_network
  ms_api_gateway:
    image: ms_api_gateway
    build:
      context: ms_api_gateway
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: ms_api_gateway
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - ms_network

This is the eureka server config(ms_service_discovery)
spring.application.name=ms_service_discovery
server.port=8761
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false

This is the eureka client config (ms_api_gateway)
spring.application.name=ms_api_gateway
server.port=8080
eureka.instance.hostname=ms_service_discovery
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:8761/eureka/

Ultimately, the gateway prints this error that says it can't find the discovery server:
2024-06-29 22:00:13 com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
2024-06-29 22:00:13     at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:112)
2024-06-29 22:00:13     at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89)
2024-06-29 22:00:13     at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$3.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:92)
2024-06-29 22:00:13     at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77)
2024-06-29 22:00:13     at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89)
2024-06-29 22:00:13     at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.renew(DiscoveryClient.java:837)
2024-06-29 22:00:13     at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient$HeartbeatThread.run(DiscoveryClient.java:1401)
2024-06-29 22:00:13     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:572)
2024-06-29 22:00:13     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
2024-06-29 22:00:13     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
2024-06-29 22:00:13     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
2024-06-29 22:00:13     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1570)
2024-06-29 22:00:44 2024-06-29 19:00:44 [DiscoveryClient-HeartbeatExecutor-0] ERROR c.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient - DiscoveryClient_MS_API_GATEWAY/cb16e4d4252a:ms_api_gateway:8080 - was unable to send heartbeat!

I read a lot of documentation and googled for a long time. Every solution I came across showed exactly what I already did from the beginning...
Tried adding many things to the configuration but to no avail.
Thanks in advance!
